# Forth syntax highlighting for Sublime Text 2?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, sublimetext2, forth, gforth

I've been looking around and haven't found a syntax definition for Gforth to use in [Sublime Text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text).

Is there one? I have found one for [TextPad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TextPad), but that's about it (see [TextPad syntax definitions](http://www.textpad.com/add-ons/syna2g.html)). Is it possible to convert the one for TextPad to work with Sublime Text 2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have [Charles Turner's Forth TextMate bundle](https://github.com/kballard/textmate-bundles/tree/master/Review/Bundles/Forth.tmbundle) installed (in Sublime Text) and it works nicely.

If that's not good enough, perhaps you could extend it with patterns gleaned from the TextPad syntax file. To learn how Sublime Text syntax definitions work, I'd read 
through *[Syntax Definitions](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/extensibility/syntaxdefs.html)*.

I hope that helps!